# How to find duplicated elements in a 1D Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to get elements that appear more than one time in a 1D tensor. Precisely, I want to create a function that does the opposite of `tf.unique`. For example if `x = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4]` I need the output to be `[1,1,4,4,4,5,5]` and at the same time also retrieve the index of those elements in the source tensor.
My final goal is to get examples in a batch that labels appear more than one times.

Comment: Phrasing clarification:  Do you really want to implement an operator, or do you simply want to implement this functionality?  (Note that in tf, you *can* implement an operator to do it, but you could also do this .. maybe .. by chaining existing tf operations together.)

Comment: Also:  Are your elements in a dense range (e.g., is the maximum value element roughly bounded by the number of elements in the list), or are they arbitrary (e.g., can you have an element whose value is 93929923923 in a list of 10 items?)

Comment: In fact, I just need the functionality. My first attempt is to use tf.unique and a double loops over the rows of the tensor and unique values and select those that are not unique. But I can't figure out how to loop over tensor. I need something like theano.scan. The value of my elements are not bounded. In reality, I'm trying to train a triplet network and I want to generate the training triplet on the fly. I have a large number of classes more than 1000. And I think that this functionality will help to select the positive elements of the triplet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using existing Tensorflow operations in a slightly round-about way, by counting the unique items to create a dense set of indexes of the unique items, and then counting them using `tf.unsorted_segment_sum`.  Once you have the count, select the items with `> N` using `tf.greater`, and gather them back into a dense list:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([8, 7, 8, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 5, 0, 5])
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

unique_a_vals, unique_idx = tf.unique(a)
count_a_unique = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(tf.ones_like(a),                   
                                         unique_idx,                        
                                         tf.shape(a)[0])                    

more_than_one = tf.greater(count_a_unique, 1)                               
more_than_one_idx = tf.squeeze(tf.where(more_than_one))                     
more_than_one_vals = tf.squeeze(tf.gather(unique_a_vals, more_than_one_idx))

# If you want the original indexes:                                         
not_duplicated, _ = tf.listdiff(a, more_than_one_vals)                      
dups_in_a, indexes_in_a = tf.listdiff(a, not_duplicated)                    

with tf.Session() as s:                                                     
    s.run(init)                                                             
    a, dupvals, dupidxes, dia = s.run([a, more_than_one_vals,                    
                                  indexes_in_a, dups_in_a])                            
    print "Input: ", a                                                      
    print "Duplicate values: ", dupvals                                     
    print "Indexes of duplicates in a: ", dupidxes
    print "Dup vals with dups: ", dia
```

> Input:  [8 7 8 1 3 4 5 9 5 0 5]
>
> Duplicate values:  [8 5]
>
> Indexes of duplicates in a:  [ 0  2  6  8 10]
>
> Dup vals with dups:  [8 8 5 5 5]

Comment: (Updated from first version to also give you the original indexes in a.)

I'm curious if someone can make a better version of this, though, that doesn't rely on the listdiff functionality.

Comment: Thank you, for this detailed answer. I got the idea. For the listdiff, do you mean that there's a better way to do this ?

Comment: I don't know. :)  There might be something more clever.  I just don't think my solution is very elegant - it uses a lot of fairly expensive operations for something that, at its heart, should be more straightforward.  This example bears thinking about a bit.